# javascript access xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am returning xmlhttprequest and am trying to access xmlhttprequest.responseText

I can use console.log and see the value of xmlhttprequest.state, but when I try to see the value of xmlhttprequest.responseText nothing comes up. Here is the responseText I get when I log the xmlhttprequest object.

```
{"name":"05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843_2009-1.jpg",
"size":54823,
"type":"application\/octet-stream",
"url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843_2009-1.jpg",
"large_url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/large\/05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843_2009-1.jpg",
"medium_url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/medium\/05571C-83E2A2D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843-2009-1.jpg",
"thumbnail_url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/thumbs\/05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843-2009-1.jpg"}"
```

I am simply trying to get this data so I can parse it with jquery.

Any ides?

Comment: If you're using jQuery anyway why aren't you using its Ajax functions? In any case, show some of your JavaScript.

Comment: The is no reason for the \ before the /

Comment: @epascarello: Yes there is. It makes the JSON script-tag-safe. If forward slashes weren't escaped a `</script>` inside the json would break it. And escaping them is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, still makes no fn sense. You are going to add how many more characters for one edge case? Make whatever is generating the JSON look for that script case. yikes.

Comment: Also what is with the extra " at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning JSON. Try using jQuery's [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) like this example:

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data){
    alert(data.name);
});
```

Comment: I would use those but it wont integrate into my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I see an extra " sign at the end of your line. That might be your problem. Example below works fine for me:

ajax.php

```
echo '{"name":"05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843_2009-1.jpg",
"size":54823,
"type":"application\/octet-stream",
"url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843_2009-1.jpg",
"large_url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/large\/05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843_2009-1.jpg",
"medium_url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/medium\/05571C-83E2A2D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843-2009-1.jpg",
"thumbnail_url":"\/admin\/..\/uploads\/thumbs\/05571C-83E2A2-D4F3F0-6D7EE3-58A5F6-606843-2009-1.jpg"}';
```

call.php

```
<a href="#" id="trigger">Alert json</a>
<script>
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax.php',
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(data) {
              $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    alert(key +":"+value); 
                });
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you want to call just one child item from encoded json you can use it like this after success:

```
success: function(data) {
alert(data.name);
alert(data.size);
}
```

Comment: You should really make the event function accept an argument and call `.preventDefault()` on this argument.

Comment: @ThiefMaster and why "should really" do that ?

Comment: Otherwise clicking the link will a) add an ugly `#` to the url in the address bar and b) jump to the top of the page. both things that are usually not wanted.

Comment: Sure it is but when you say "should really" it sound like if you dont use preventDefault it wont work :)

Comment: If you ever have a link that should work without JS (i.e. a real target, not just a hash) it won't work without preventDefault.